# comparing a string value returned from ToArray() method in c#

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Following is a code written by me for searching a specific item by name in the Advertisement table.

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(string name)
{
    var advertisement = db.Advertisements.ToArray(); // retrieve data from database
    foreach (var ad in advertisement)
    {
        if (ad.Title.Equals(name))
        {
            return View(ad); 
        }
    }

    return View(advertisement);
}
```

Even though I search an item which is already in the database, in all cases the if condition is not being true.Each time I get the whole list of items as the result in the view page. what is the issue here?

My model for Advertisement looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing; // Image type is in this namespace
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Bartering.Models
{
    public class Advertisement
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public Guid OwnerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Comment: Well have you debugged through to validate that you really do get the expected object back? Have you checked that you're receiving `name` properly?

Comment: Try with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` with ignore

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried debugging, and surprisingly the value for name is null

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing something like this

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(string name)
{
   var ad=db.Advertisements.Where(s=>s.Title.ToUpper()==name.ToUpper())
                  .FirstOrDefault();
   if(ad!=null)
      return View(ad);
   //Nothing found for search for the name, Let's return the "NotFound" view
   return View("NotFound");
}
```

This code will get the first item(if exists) which matches with our check (Title==name) and return it. if there is nothing found which matches the condition, It will return a View called "Notfound"

Comment: I tried this and it routes to the notfound view even when i search for an item already in the database

Comment: Put visual studio breakpoints in your method and see what are you getting in the `db.Adverisements` collection and see whether you have an entry with Title property value matching to your `name` variable value

Comment: That means you are not posting it properly to your action method. Is the textbox name in your view is `name` ?

Comment: I just noticed, that It is not "name" and now when I debug i get the value typed for name. Thanks a lot

Comment: It works fine now with my code itself. Thank you for the guide